# How to convert Text 25:40:45 to 1:40:45 (24 hours format) in Python

Tags: python, time

Need some help on this. Not sure how to start.
I have list of starting time which looks like
[image]

How can I get the Clean_Start_Time in Python from Start_Time (string)? 25h is supposed to be 0100 and 24h is 0000.

Comment: Hour modulo 24?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. It splits the string on `:`, gets the remainder of the hour divided by twenty four then joins the string back together and returns it.

```
def modulo24(start_time):
    hour, minute, second = start_time.split(':')
    hour = str(int(hour) % 24)
    clean_start_time = ":".join([hour, minute, second])
    return clean_start_time
```